# How to get a single model object with a relation to the template in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am working on this project that I can add two or more forms in a template. I am able to get the two forms in the template but when I submit the form, I get the objects for the rentalproperty model and not the contract model. I have created two different solution but the two doesn't solve the problem.

The first solution below display both objects multiple times in the detailview but what I want is to display the two model objects just once. The second solution display the rentalproperty object once but the contract objects multiple times. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

First solution:
views.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = RentalProperty
    template_name = 'rental/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'property'



def new_rental(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rental_form = NewRentalPropertyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix = "rentals")
        contract_form = NewContractForm(request.POST, prefix = "contracts")
        if rental_form.is_valid() and contract_form.is_valid():
            print ("all validation passed")
            rentalproperty = rental_form.save()
            contract_form.cleaned_data["rentalproperty"] = rentalproperty
            print(contract_form)
            contract = contract_form.save(commit=False)
            contract.rentalproperty = rentalproperty
            contract = contract_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home"))
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error")
            contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=pk)

    else: 
        rental_form = NewRentalPropertyForm(prefix = "rentals")
        contract_form = NewContractForm(prefix = "contracts")
        contract = Contract.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'rental/new_rental.html', {
        #'rentalproperty': rentalproperty,
    'rental_form': rental_form,
    'contract_form': contract_form,
    'contract': contract,

    })
```

detail.html

```
<h1>This is the detail view</h1>
    <h3>From landlord</h3>
    <p>Landlord: {{property.created_by}}</p>
    <p>address: {{property.landlord.address}}</p>

    <h3>From Rental property</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for rental in property.landlord.rentalpropertys.all %}
        <br>
        <li>Title: {{property.title}}</li>
    <img src="{{property.image.url}}" height="200" alt=""/>
    <li>created at: {{property.created_at}}</li>
    <li>Type of property: {{property.type_of_property_listing}}</li>
    <li>Street: {{property.street}}</li>
    <li>Borough: {{property.borough}}</li>
        <ul>
            {% for contract in rental.contracts.all %}
            <li> Insurance required: {{contract.insurance_required}}</li>
            <li> other terms: {{contract.other_terms}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Second solution:

views.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = RentalProperty
    template_name = 'rental/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'property'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['landlord']= Landlord.objects.all()
        context['contract']= Contract.objects.filter(rentalproperty__title=title).order_by('created_at')
        return context
```

The post function is the same.

detail.html

```
<h1>This is the detail view</h1>
    <h3>From landlord</h3>
    <p>Landlord: {{property.created_by}}</p>
    <p>address: {{property.landlord.address}}</p>

    <h3>From Rental property</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Title: {{property.title}}</li>
        <img src="{{property.image.url}}" height="200" alt=""/>
        <li>created at: {{property.created_at}}</li>
        <li>Type of property: {{property.type_of_property_listing}}</li>
        <li>Street: {{property.street}}</li>
        <li>Borough: {{property.borough}}</li>

        </ul>

        <ul>
        {% for data in contract %}
        <li> insurance : {{data.insurance_required}}</li>
        <li> other terms: {{data.other_terms}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

My model:

```
class Landlord(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.address)


class RentalProperty(models.Model):
    landlord = models.ForeignKey("Landlord", related_name='rentalpropertys', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, related_name='rentalpropertys', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    PROPERTY_LISTING_CHOICES = Choices(
        ('APARTMENT', _('Apartment')),
        ('HOLIDAY_HOME', _('Holiday home')),
        ('SINGLE_FAMILY_HOME', _('Single family home')),
        ('COMMERCIAL', _('Commercial')),
    )
    type_of_property_listing = models.CharField(
        max_length = 50,
        choices = PROPERTY_LISTING_CHOICES,
        default = PROPERTY_LISTING_CHOICES.APARTMENT,)

    street = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    borough = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

class Contract(models.Model):
    rentalproperty = models.ForeignKey("RentalProperty", related_name='contracts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    insurance_required = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    other_terms = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.insurance_required)
```

first solution output:

address: Helsinki
title: build apps
insurance: Yes
- This repeats itself multiple times.

Second solution output:

address: Helsinki
title: build apps
insurance: Yes
- insurance repeats itself multiple times

What I expect:
address: Helsinki
title: build apps
insurance: Yes

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Is this homework? If you don't want the insurance details to repeat, you need to understand what the contents of the `contract` variable in your template is and what the `for` is doing

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony No, it is not an homework. It is a project I am building to learn Django. Except I dont understand your question, the for is to iterate through the data and return the specific objects relating to the id, at least,  that is what I expect.

Comment: OK, what exactly do you want to display? You want to show the single rental property and just one contract (that relates to that property)?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony exactly. That is my intention but from the first solution I was getting multiple instances of the rental property and contract and the second one instance of the rental property but multiple instance of the related contracts.

Comment: Got it. Can you post your models for `RentalProperty` and `Contract`. You should be able to use the loop in your template `{% for contract in property.contract_set.all %}` in your template to loop through only the contracts that belong to the rental property.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony I posted my model. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Timmy O'Mahony answer, I did {% for contract in property.contracts.all %} in my template using the first solutions and it works. The contracts is the related name to the rental property. Thanks all.